# How to replace CIFAR-10 with another custom dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am  very new to tensorflow.

I am using the CIFAR10 (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) example and everything is smooth so far.
In this tutorial, How I can use another dataset instead of CIFAR10.
Lets say I have my own dataset and wanna use it instead. It has two folders inside of it, namely Training_Images and Testing_Images.
Also lets say for simplicity my dataset has just 10 classes as well.
In other words, I have a traininng and testing folder of images, and in each folder, i have images of each category (with the same lable) in a folder. I dont know how to feed the network with those images.

I also have read (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) but didnot really got my answer from it and didnot understand it clearly.

Also, if you guys know of any good example, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this yourself?

Comment: Are those images also in the CIFAR-10 binary format?  If not, you'll have to supply a compatible input routine, as well.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I am working on it, I am reading to know where to start from....

Comment: @Prune they are not binary format actually, they are png format

Comment: If your files are raw image files (i.e. .png, .jpeg, etc ...) then you're going to need to load them as either numpy arrays or pack them into a binary format.  I'd look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py) for loading your data into binary format and [scikit image](http://scikit-image.org/) is a great resource for loading raw image files into numpy arrays.  But as this question stands, it is a bit too broad.  Try using those resources and when you get stuck, come back and ask a more specific question.

Comment: @gobrewers14 I will look at that. Thanks